# Is it possible to use transactions with th Classes API in orientjs?

Tags: orientdb, orientjs

I can't seem to find anything in the documentation around the usage of transactions with Classes API.

There is a `Db#begin()` method that starts a new transaction. So given the code below:

```
const db = server.use('MyDb');
const transaction = db.begin();
const Product = await transaction.db.class.get('Product');
//Transaction already gets committed to the database here before commit is executed
await Product.create({name: 'Milk', brand: 'Clover'})  
transaction.commit()
```

I would have thought the transaction would only be committed on `transaction.commit()` but it gets is committed immediately. I know about the `db.let()` syntax but something like above would be a lot easier to work with.

I don't see the value of the `Class#create(record)` method if you can't use it with a transaction. Which makes me believe I'm missing something but I've been racking my brain on this for the last day.

Comment: HI Marthinus Engelbrecht, which version of Orientdb you use?

Comment: I attempted this in 2.2. But don't see anything in the documentation about it in 3